# Incrementally count row numbers for distrinct rows in a join select

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, join, row-number

I have a select that joins two tables, `a` and `b`, via a join table, `ab`.

```
select a.*, b.* 
from a 
left join ab on a.id = ab.aid 
left join b  on b.id = ab.bid;
```

And this produces

```
 id |  athing  | id |  bthing   
----+----------+----+-----------
  7 | athing x |  1 | bthing a
  7 | athing x |  2 | bthing b
  7 | athing x |  3 | bthing c
  3 | athing y |  1 | bthing a
(4 rows)
```

I want a column that incrementally counts the number of rows in `a`. That is:

```
 count | id |  athing  | id |  bthing   
-------+----+----------+----+-----------
   1   |  7 | athing x |  1 | bthing a
   1   |  7 | athing x |  2 | bthing b
   1   |  7 | athing x |  3 | bthing c
   2   |  3 | athing y |  1 | bthing a
(4 rows)
```

I have looked at using the window function `row_number()`, but that seems to count all the rows.

I want to incrementally count the distinct `a` rows, regardless of how many rows the joined table creates.

Is this possible in Postgresql? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()` when selecting from the table `a` (note, the order of the rows in `a` is defined in `over` clause):

```
select a.*, b.*
from (
    select row_number() over (order by id desc) as count, *
    from a 
    ) a
left join ab on a.id = ab.aid 
left join b  on b.id = ab.bid;

 count | id |  athing  | id |  bthing  
-------+----+----------+----+----------
     1 |  7 | athing x |  1 | bthing a
     1 |  7 | athing x |  2 | bthing b
     1 |  7 | athing x |  3 | bthing c
     2 |  3 | athing y |  1 | bthing a
(4 rows)
```

or `dense_rank()` on the result dataset.

```
select 
    dense_rank() over (order by a.id desc) as count,
    a.*, b.*
from a 
left join ab on a.id = ab.aid 
left join b  on b.id = ab.bid;
```

Read about [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html).